# Error while generating getters and setters

Tags: symfony

After doing this : `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities Datacenter`

I'm getting the following error :

```
  [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@validation:Validation" in property Datacenter\AssetsManagerBundle\
  Entity\CommentDoc::$name was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this an
  notation?
```

By the way I'm following the official doc http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/2-0/doc/tutorial/creating_your_first_admin_class/defining_entities.html

And it breaks when generating getters and setters :p

Any Ideas ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is explicit : `Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this an notation?`

Add this into your CommentDoc class

`use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as validation;`

see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Hope it's helpful

Best regard